# Converting SQL commands to Python's ORM

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

**How would you convert the following codes to Python's ORM such as by SQLalchemy?**

## #1 Putting data to Pg

```
import os, pg, sys, re, psycopg2                                                       

#conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='tkk' host='localhost' port='5432' user='noa' password='123'")

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=tk user=naa password=123")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO courses (course_nro)
            VALUES ( %(course_nro)s )""", dict(course_nro='abcd'))
conn.commit()
```

## #2 Fetching

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM courses")
print cur.fetchall()
```

## Examples about the two commands in [SQLalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/sqlalchemy/expressions.html)

**insert**

```
sqlalchemy.sql.expression.insert(table, values=None, inline=False, **kwargs)
```

**select**

```
sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select(columns=None, whereclause=None, from_obj=[], **kwargs)
```

Comment: When you read the SQLAlchemy site, what examples did they give of INSERT and SELECT.  Please update this question to include the example code from the SQLAlchemy site.

Comment: So, you have the SQLAlchemy code.  What -- specifically -- are you asking?  You have the code.  What's wrong with the code you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the initial declarations, you can do something like this:

```
o = Course(course_nro='abcd')
session.add(o)
session.commit()
```

and

```
print session.query(Course).all()
```

The declarations could look something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import session_maker

# create an engine, and a base class
engine = create_engine('postgre://naa:123@localhost/tk')
DeclarativeBase = declarative_base(bind=engine)
metadata = DeclarativeBase.metadata

# create a session
Session = session_maker(engine)
session = Session()

# declare the models
class Cource(DelcarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'courses'

    course_nro = Column('course_nro', CHAR(12))
```

This declarative method is just one way of using sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is old, more examples can't hurt, right? I thought I'd demonstrate how to do this with [PyORMish](http://pyormish.nullism.com).

```
from pyormish import Model

class Course(Model):
    _TABLE_NAME = 'courses'
    _PRIMARY_FIELD = 'id' # or whatever your primary field is
    _SELECT_FIELDS = ('id','course_nro')
    _COMMIT_FIELDS = ('course_nro',)

Model.db_config = dict(
    DB_TYPE='postgres',
    DB_CONN_STRING='postgre://naa:123@localhost/tk'
)
```

To create:

```
new_course = Course().create(course_nro='abcd')
```

To select:

```
# return the first row WHERE course_nro='abcd'
new_course = Course().get_by_fields(course_nro='abcd')
```